# Windows drivers - communicate with user process

Tags: device, drivers

I have written a application in Qt and what is the best way to communicate with a custom USB device (does not belong to any class - need to write custom drivers for it) under Windows. In Linux I could just share the data with user space from the /dev or /sys filesystems. What are the equivalent alternative in Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of user-space USB libraries for Windows. While Microsoft do provide [WinUSB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly, I'd recommend using either [libusbx](http://libusbx.org/) or [libusb](http://libusb.org/) and installing the driver for your device with [zadig](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwdi/files/zadig/).

Using libusbx rather than the Microsoft driver directly has the advantage of being easier to port to other operating systems, which might be a consideration for you as you are using Qt.